# Can't access button/textarea in the handle event

Tags: java, javafx

I've just started using JavaFX and have been trying to add an event that will add text to a textarea and clear a text field when you press the 'send' button. However, I can't seem to check the source of the event in the handle method.

I've tried to search for a solution, but others don't seem to face the same issue - either that or I'm missing something obvious.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ApplicationMain extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    Stage window;

    // Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // Scene Method
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Window Stuff
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Chat Application");

        // Setup Grid Layout
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #272828;");

        // MenuBar
        MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();

        menu.setPrefWidth(1000);
        menu.setPrefHeight(20);

        // Creation of File + Help
        Menu file = new Menu("File");
        Menu help = new Menu("Help");

        // Add the Menus to the MenuBar
        menu.getMenus().add(file);
        menu.getMenus().add(help);

        // Add MenuBar to Scene
        menu.setVisible(true);
        grid.add(menu, 0, 0);

        // Text Area Stuff
        TextArea area = new TextArea();

        area.setPrefWidth(1000);
        area.setPrefHeight(700);
        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: #313233;");

        // Add Text Area to Grid
        grid.add(area, 0, 1);

        // Text Field
        TextField enter = new TextField();

        enter.setPromptText("Type here...");
        enter.setMaxWidth(920);
        enter.setMaxHeight(30);
        enter.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5px;");

        // Button
        Button send = new Button("Send!");

        // Set the Handler for the Send Button Event
        send.setOnAction(this);

        // Use of HBox to Space out Text Field & Send Button
        HBox row = new HBox();

        row.setSpacing(10);
        row.setHgrow(enter, Priority.ALWAYS);
        row.getChildren().addAll(enter, send);

        // Use of VBox to Space out Text Field
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.setSpacing(10);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        box.getChildren().add(row);

        // Add HBox in VBox to Grid
        grid.add(box, 0, 2);

        // Scene Stuff
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 1000, 750);
        window.setScene(scene);

        // Display the Window
        window.show();
    }

    // Event Handler
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource() == send) {

        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to check if the source was the button 'send', it doesn't show up -  as if it's not accessible by the method. I'm unsure of how to fix this.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. Many chunks of this code are not essential to illustrate the question. This code does not compile.

Answer (score 3):

There is a few things wrong with this code but we can fix it no problemo.

First learn naming conventions and stick to them as @kleopatra says if you google java naming conventions you will be overloaded with many results read a few

Next you shouldn't call a `Stage` a `window` there is already another object that has that name so it may confuse others but if its only for you its ok I guess

I wouldn't `@SuppressWarnings("static-access")` as you have done if you have an error fix it don't ignore it

The `send.setOnAction(this);` is not the way to handle events remove your `implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>` you can use the event handler by setting it like this

```
send.setOnAction(event -> sendToTextArea(enter.getText(), area));
```

And this is what the method you are calling should look like

```
private void sendToTextArea(String string, TextArea textArea){
    //textArea.setText(string);Use setText if you want to set the whole area to something
    textArea.appendText(string+"\n");//Use appendText to append add new line because chat app
}
```

Eveything else looks good here is what your final product should look like

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // stage Stuff
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle("Chat Application");

        // Setup Grid Layout
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #272828;");

        // MenuBar
        MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();

        menu.setPrefWidth(1000);
        menu.setPrefHeight(20);

        // Creation of File + Help
        Menu file = new Menu("File");
        Menu help = new Menu("Help");

        // Add the Menus to the MenuBar
        menu.getMenus().add(file);
        menu.getMenus().add(help);

        // Add MenuBar to Scene
        menu.setVisible(true);
        grid.add(menu, 0, 0);

        // Text Area Stuff
        TextArea area = new TextArea();

        area.setPrefWidth(1000);
        area.setPrefHeight(700);
        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: #313233;");

        // Add Text Area to Grid
        grid.add(area, 0, 1);

        // Text Field
        TextField enter = new TextField();

        enter.setPromptText("Type here...");
        enter.setMaxWidth(920);
        enter.setMaxHeight(30);
        enter.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5px;");

        // Button
        Button send = new Button("Send!");

        // Set the Handler for the Send Button Event
        send.setOnAction(event -> sendToTextArea(enter, area));

        // Use of HBox to Space out Text Field & Send Button
        HBox row = new HBox();

        row.setSpacing(10);
        row.setHgrow(enter, Priority.ALWAYS);
        row.getChildren().addAll(enter, send);

        // Use of VBox to Space out Text Field
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.setSpacing(10);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        box.getChildren().add(row);

        // Add HBox in VBox to Grid
        grid.add(box, 0, 2);

        // Scene Stuff
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 1000, 750);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // Display the stage
        stage.show();
    }

    private void sendToTextArea(TextField textField, TextArea textArea){
        //textArea.setText(string);Use setText if you want to set the whole area to something
        //textArea.clear();and .clear to clear all text from the TextArea
        textArea.appendText(textField.getText()+"\n");//Use appendText to append add new line because chat app
        textField.clear();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `TextArea` and `TextField` class variables:

```
private TextArea area;
private TextField enter;
```

Change their initialization:

```
// Text Area Stuff
area = new TextArea();
// Text Field
enter = new TextField();
```

And your event handler :

```
// Event Handler
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    area.setText(enter.getText());
}
```

If any of these changes is not clear, do not hesitate to ask.